# Is it ok to power an SSD without SATA plug

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I plan two have two operating systems installed on two hard drives. Each operating should not have access to the other one. I will restrict that on a hardware level by simply plugging the disk out. I want to plug out only the SATA cable of each disk as this is the most easiest solution in my cable setup. However I heard that some disks auto wipe thereself if they have power but no SATA connection, is that ture? By the way, one disk is an SSD and the other one an HDD, maybe this helps!

Comment: "_I heard that some disks auto wipe thereself if they have power but no SATA connection_" ... where did you hear this?? it sounds like an incredibly **dangerous** "_feature_", and would probably drive me away from ever touching that manufacturer again...

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this if your HDD doesn't support staggered spin-up. HDDs without SSU (or without motherboard's SSU support) will spin up with just power connected. It's not good for longevity.

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of such a thing, and such a design would be very poor. There is no need to wipe the drive, and drives should be designed to avoid data loss. I have not tried every SATA drive in existence so cannot definitively say that no SATA disk has such a bug.

If you are concerned about this, you could try your SATA immediately after installing the operating system before putting any data on it. Or you could try this immediately after doing a backup, (which you should do anyway, right?)